# How do I upload files with Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

How do I upload files with Firebase? I'm coding Swift 3. I can not find the source.

Comment: Could you add some more information on what you've tried?  Stack Overflow isn't for providing tutorials -- we'll help fix specific problems.

Comment: Did you try the documentation: [Upload Files on iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you should install pod. Add it to your podfile:

```
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
```

Then `pod install` in terminal.

Then:

```
import FirebaseStorage
```

Add this import to your file.

Then do something like this:

```
let ref = FIRStorage.storage().reference(withPath: "YOURPATH")
ref.put(data) // data - is your Data var
```

For example with image:

```
let ref = FIRStorage.storage().reference(withPath: "media/userMainPhoto").child(userId + ".jpeg")
let data: Data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "photo.jpeg"), 0.8)! // for compression and converting image to data
ref.put(data) // data - is your Data var
```

It's the simplest way to do it.

Hope it helps

Comment: Minor typo in first line (i.e. *istall*). Otherwise, pretty nice answer ;-)

Comment: @PauloMattos edited. Thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

For uploading file in fireBase you need to use Firebase storage.please follow the Link.Google has provide some sample code and step by step instruction to configure firebase with iOS.

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-ios-swift/#3